# Error: cannot find symbol class Builder (using GeoApiContext)

Tags: android, google-directions-api

I am trying to execute Direction API from the code below:

```
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
            .apiKey("MyAPIKey")
            .build();
```

and I receive the following error:

> error: cannot find symbol class Builder

I am very new to this. I have checked the other posts but still don't seem to find a solution. It would be great if you can let me know what to do.

Comment: Did you add google-maps-services dependency to your pom.xml (if using maven) or gradle file? and if so, did you add the actual version for that dependency instead of "(insert latest version)"

Answer (score 0):

replace the dependency of gradle file
`implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.9.3'`